# Navigation and Tab View controllers don't load correctly, then jump into place

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

When I try to present a TabViewController, I get odd behavior from both my TabBar and NavigationBar as seen in the images below. It stays as shown in the "before" image until I touch the screen or push a button. At the point it jumps to the "after" image.

Before: [image] 
After:

[image]

Code used to present the TabViewController:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
delegate.tabViewController = TabViewController()
self.present(delegate.tabViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Initialization of the TabViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let groupTable = GroupTableViewController()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: groupTable)
    nav.title = "Groups"
    nav.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "groups")

    let vc2 = MeViewController()
    vc2.title = "Me"
    vc2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "user")
    // let vc3 = SettingsViewController
    // vc3.title = "Settings"
    // vc3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "settings")

    self.viewControllers = [nav, vc2]
    self.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Console log, but I don't think the error is relevant:

```
objc[63765]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11916f998) and /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x118069d38).
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

This is a new bug I've been experiencing seemingly after updating to Xcode 8.1/MacOS Sierra.

My XCode version is Version 8.1 beta (8T47). Could this be a bug in the beta?

I'm unsure what is causing this as I didn't make a code change when this started happening.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` of the tab view controller is really too late to be configuring the tab view controller with its two child view controllers. Either do this in the "Code used to present the TabViewController", or, if you really want to do it from within the tab view controller itself, do it from the tab view controller's initializer. Then all will be well.

Comment: I tried configuring the tab view controller in both places with no luck, still having that weird display issue.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the issue, and even the little code you've shown is very strange (talking to the app delegate in order to present a view controller??), so who knows, overall, what you're doing? You have not given enough information.

Comment: I believe at the time, I ended up just rebuilding it as I couldn't find anything that would cause this issue, sorry to disappoint.